# postgresql のcase文で値取得時エラーが出てしまいました。

Tags: sql, postgresql

sql文

```
SELECT STORE_DM ,AG_DM 
CASE WHEN rg_dm = store_dm 
          THEN store_dm
          ELSE 'NULL' 
　　　　　 END  
          FROM member;
```

上記を実行したら下記エラーが出ました。
どうしたら条件を実行できるか教えて頂きたいです。

条件
CASE式でstore_dm項目について
rg_dm = store_dmの場合store_dm、
そうでない場合はnullにしたい。

エラー

```
SELECT STORE_DM ,AG_DM 
CASE WHEN rg_dm = store_dm 
          THEN store_dm
          ELSE 'NULL'   
          FROM member;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

外部サイトの[もしかしてマルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/317272)の回答にあるように、`AG_DM`とcase文の間のカンマが抜けています。